# How to rename files ramdomly using Python

Tags: python, dataset

I have a folder of .tiff images. I want to renames these files. This folder has a three different kind of weeds, for example broad leaf has name starting form 1-100, then soil has name starting from 101-200, similarly so on, Now I want to shuffle these file and rename them like 1,2,3... in the same directory using python. Can anyone tell me how to do this using Python.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also your explanation of what your file structure is/what you want it to be is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
import os
import random

def shuffle_and_rename(dirpath):
    l = list(filter(lambda f: os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dirpath, f)), os.listdir(dirpath)))
    random.shuffle(l)
    for ind, i in enumerate(l):
        os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, i), os.path.join(dirpath, f"{ind + 1}.tiff"))
```

Give this function the name of the folder containing the images.

This may erase some files if they are already named as 1.tiff, 2.tiff etc. So, it's always nice to have a copy of all files inside some another folder if you are not sure that no files already contain such names.